# Adding data to DB via Django Admin panel

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a new Django project using Python 3.7 and Django 1.8 I’ve made a model, migration, superuser account. But admin panel won’t work when I’m trying to add anything in it. Why this error occurs and how to fix it?

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZyxL.jpg)

Comment: did you manage to login to admin page?

Comment: Yes, I did. It works until I try to add an entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Python 3.7 Compatibility Issue with Django 1.8. The django developers actually solved this about [6 years ago](https://github.com/django/django/commit/3f2de803181ca3c5526ec9d708b2098b8f683808)

**How To Fix:** Basically your Django Version is very old and you should upgrade it to at least v1.8.6 (I recommend you upgrade it to 3.x, but do what you want), and when you do, the problem shouldn't happen any longer.

(If this doesn't work, please tell me and I can help you debug)

Comment: Yes, thank you! Installation Django v 2.2 fixed the problem